# SO(2) group generator Lie Algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics, infinite-groups

For the $2 \times 2$ orthogonal group of matrices which for the $SO(2)$ group, there is only one free parameter in the group element and hence only one generator for the group. Which is,

$$ X_g = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0  & -1 \\
1 &  0 \end{array} \right) $$

Now if this generator has to form Lie Algebra, it has to satisfy the Jacobi Identity and commutators. I don't understand how to do this with just one element.

Comment: There is only one element(generator) in Lie-algebra, am not talking about the group. (No. of generators = No. of parameters in the group)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the Lie group $SO(2)$ is abelian it has trivial Lie algebra, i.e., with zero Lie brackets. The "generator of rotations" is indeed $X_g$, which does not imply that the group has only one generator. Note that
$$
X_g=\frac{d}{d\alpha}R(\alpha)\mid_{\alpha=0},
$$
where $R(\alpha)$ are the rotation matrices.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks !! I think I have problem in the terminology "generator". Nevertheless, got the point